# Need help extracting data from a pipe-separated text file

Tags: ruby

Here is my array:

```
http://imdb.com/title/tt0111161/?ref_=chttp_tt_1|The Shawshank Redemption|1994|USA|1994-10-14|Crime,Drama|142 min|9.3|Frank Darabont|Tim Robbins,Morgan Freeman,Bob Gunton
http://imdb.com/title/tt0068646/?ref_=chttp_tt_2|The Godfather|1972|USA|1972-03-24|Crime,Drama|175 min|9.2|Francis Ford Coppola|Marlon Brando,Al Pacino,James Caan
....., etc. (250 films)
```

And my code, which gives me the hash:

```
file = IO.read("movies.txt")
new_arr = file.split("\n")
new_xd = new_arr.map{ |e| s = e.split("|")
 {url: s[0], title: s[1], Year: s[2], Country: s[3], Full_Year: s[4], 
 Genre: s[5], Time: s[6],Rating: s[7], Director: s[8], Actor: s[9]}
}
```

I would like to list all unique directors and sort the result alphabetically by last name. I am having difficulty finding a way to sort by last name. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Unrelated to the point, are you sure you want to sort names of western origin by the last name? Name order is culture-specific. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_name#Name_order) for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by can help you:

```
pry(main)> new_xd.map{|movie| movie[:Director].split(',')}.flatten.uniq.sort_by{|director_full_name| director_full_name.split(' ').last}
=> ["Francis Ford Coppola", "Frank Darabont"]
```

Comment: Do you have more information, and the associated error message?
I only could test with the two lines you provided, and it works.
Maybe the director information is missing for some movies.

Answer (score 0):

You can get unique names of directors using this code. Provided that a movie can have several directors, you may want to handle them individually, by using `split(',')`.

```
new_xd.map { |movie| movie[:Director].split(',') }.flatten.uniq
```